# VirtualBox Win7 enable horizontal trackpad scrolling

Tags: windows, magic-trackpad, virtualbox

I use a Windows 7 installtion in Virtual Box. The magic track works fine for scrolling up and down but scrolling sideways doesn't work. Does anyone know how to get it working?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: no, i switched to parallels which had a much better support for this stuff + it mapped the mac shortcuts in a way that they worked on windows (if i remember this correctly)